# How can I use relative paths in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

My Project path is:

**C:/Projects/base/ProductA**

In its CMakeLists.txt I set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` which path is:
**C:/Projects/base/Util/etc/cmake/Modules**

I set an absolute path and it works.

`set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "C:/Projects/base/Util/etc/cmake/Modules;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")`

How to set relative path: something like "..Util/etc/cmake/Modules"
I tried relative, but it doesn't work (error thrown, so only absolute paths work).

Comment: [Please see doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html). Note: `By default it is empty. It is intended to be set by the project.`

Comment: Personally I tend to treat these kinds of variables as lists and add to the end to allow the user to replace the module by providing `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` as cache variable during configuration: `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Util/etc/cmake/Modules)`

Comment: @fabian thanks - when you say you "add to the end" - I need it at the begging of the script after the Project Name - is it OK to have after the project() segment?

Comment: @vel I wasn't referring to the location of the command, but rather to `list(APPEND)` vs `list(PREPEND)`, i.e. adding the path to your own modules to the end or the start of the list variable. Where you put the command modifying the variable is irrelevant as long as it happens before `find_package`.

Comment: @fabian thanks - with small correction  to relative path (..) I think `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Util/etc/cmake/Modules` works you can put this as an answer so I can mark it. Thank you all for kind assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that relative paths are not supported by `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. There's a related mail thread on this [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-February/027068.html). Some commands do, such as `add_subdirectory`, or `add_executable` / `add_library` / `target_sources`. Usually, when relative paths are supported, the docs will explicitly say so, and say what they are resolved relative to in those cases. See also some related wiki FAQs, such as [Why does CMake use full paths, or can I copy my build tree?](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#why-does-cmake-use-full-paths-or-can-i-copy-my-build-tree)

There are plenty of variables you can use to anchor a path to some other absolute directory path, such as [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html), [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html), [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html),  and [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html).

Ex. if `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` is `C:/Projects/base/ProductA`, then you could use `list(PREPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Util/etc/cmake/Modules;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")`. Note: That feels a little weird though. If the Util project is in a separate repo, you're basically requiring users of the project to clone things in specific locations relative to each other, which is more tightly coupled than I would do in my own projects. I'd instead give users a variable they can set which points to where the Utils project is cloned to.